# Is the depiction of nudity or sex harmful to minors?

Tags: psychology, sexuality, children, art

In other words, are the censorship & ratings of movies and other forms of art based on something more than nothing? ;) Or, in a broader sense, I am questioning the very widespread belief that kids should not be allowed to watch anything sex-related.

I am talking only the ratings/censorship based on the nudity, sex, explicitness, etc., i.e. not violence, profanity, drugs and other things movies can get bad MPAA rating (or an equivalent).

Please no anecdotal evidences, nor any discussions about whether kids should be interested in these things, or do they (should they?) understand them, and so forth. I am only interested in the direct and measurable harm aspect.

Comment: That depends on how you define "harmful"  otherwise the question is unanswerable. There obviously ARE effects, whether you consider them harmful or not is a different thing. Also, you didn't mention whether it's only direct effects or secondary? E.g. if (theoretically) there was a measurable effect of earlier sexual activity, do you include any effects that are known to be consequences of that?

Comment: You can just provide well documented examples of what You would consider harmful, or what you think other people can reasonably consider harmful, or what the researches considered harmful, etc. Sexual activity is not harmful by any stretch of imagination, on the contrary, I can provide quite a few links to researches showing it's positive effects to health - and negative effects of abstinence.

Comment: "**earlier** sexual activity", not simply "sexual activity". Which could theoretically include consequences such as underage pregnancy, higher rate of STDs, problems with relating to romantic partners long term (I seem to vaguely recall a study of that being a problem with hook-up culture), problems with academic stuff (due to screwing around instead of studying) etc... Please note that I'm making plausible stuff up, NOT siting specific research :) It is quite possible that none of those are proven to be even indirect effects.

Comment: Well "can theoretically include" is a speculation, "does include as proven by the research X" is a fact and a real harm. I do understand you are talking hypothetically, and I am pretty sure we both understand "harm" the same or nearly the same way. There's really not much to discuss here, and in the unlikely event you will find some sort of harm that I don't consider harmful, it's still gonna be an interesting research ;)

Comment: This empty space is documented evidence that there does not exist such documented evidence

Comment: If only proving a negative were so easy.

Comment: The statement "Depictions of nudity/sex are harmful to minors" is not a negative. Hence proving it isn't impossible. A bit more serious, please :)

Comment: @Lagerbaer I believe mmr was refering to solomoan's lack of evidence of an effect as an evidence of a lack of effect.

Comment: Converted to comment.

Comment: The question title contains the word "harmful" but the question body leaves it undefined.  Either define it, or remove it from the title.  Poor questions harm this site more than anything else.

Comment: @ Adam: try dictionary. The title also containts undefined words "any", "documented", "evidence", "of", "depiction", "nudity", "or", "sex", "being", "harmful", "to", "minors".

Comment: @Sejanus One definition is [moral evil or wrongdoing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/harm). The other words are narrowly defined enough for this question, but this one is not, and in fact your comments themselves suggest that it's subjective. Consider following the advice found in the faq: *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions"* As written, your question is unanswerable, and in fact you've already rejected at least one good studies-based answer because you rejected their definition of "harmful". Might as well close this question as "not a real question/unanswerable".

Comment: @ Adam just because you don't know what harmful is doesn't mean most of the people don't too. This is a perfectly good question. It's just that probably there aren't any studies that found anything harmful about seeing naked people and/or sex.

Comment: Actually the idea that some consensual acts are "harmful" is always vague. I would argue that romance is dangerous (many scientists agree) because it encourage marriage that leads to alimony. Porn is not that dangerous.

Comment: There's relevant information [in this paper](http://www.scribd.com/doc/30328730/Childhood-Exposure-to-Parental-Nudity-Parent-Child-Co-Sleeping-and-Primal-Scenes), I might write an answer based on it later.

Comment: Certainly--depictions of nudity & sex can provoke major outrage.  A very low but non-zero percentage of such people will die of heart attacks, leaving said minor minus a parent.

Comment: “Or, in a broader sense, I am questioning the very widespread belief that kids should not be allowed to watch anything sex-related.” Is this really a *broader* sense? Or is it a *narrower* sense, as it conflates nudity and sex?

Comment: Is this question just about *depictions* of nudity or sex, or does it also include minors *directly witnessing* these things, as discussed in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems that all of the answers have gravitated towards depictions of sex. Either because nudity equals sex (while in Hollywood, this appears to generally be the case - it's extremely rare to see a nude scene that isn't purely for titillation, rather than because someone just woke up or got out of the shower), or because it hadn't occurred to them that they might be separate.

If you want to know if *social* nudity - namely nudity that is purely nonsexual - has any effect on children, just ask a nudist.

[This document](http://www.montananaturist.org/Naturism%20and%20Children.html) explains one nudist club's stance on the effects of social nudity on children, and cites several studies. The conclusion they reach is that there is absolutely no *negative* effect, and there may be a positive effect on the psyche. The basic nudist philosophy is that the extreme modesty of the Victorian era was in fact harmful (which was proven by many studies before and since), and as such, perhaps its inverse - a total lack of modesty - is beneficial.

Studies aside, nudists themselves have observed no obvious negative effects in children - very young children especially *like* to be naked, and generally the idea that there's nothing inherently wrong with the human body in its natural state promotes better body image in older children as well. See the bottom of the document above about Casler's study, and the older children's reactions in his interviews.

It's generally parents' negative reactions to nudity in TV and film that are most harmful to children. Especially if that reaction is particularly unhinged and panicked - see also:

[Super Bowl XXXVIII halftime show controversy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XXXVIII_halftime_show_controversy)

Edit:

There was a paper written on this subject (actually, of children witnessing *parental* nudity and sexual activity, which of course, is different from what you see on TV, since parents have such a central and authoritative role in a child's life) in the Journal of Sex Research. The paper can be found on [here](http://www.freebeaches.org.nz/TAASALibrary52.pdf).

> Consistent with the
>   cross-sectional retrospective literature (and with our expectations), no harmful main
>   effects of these experiences were found at age 17-18. Indeed, trends in the data that were
>   significant at p [less than] 0.05 but did not reach significance following the Bonferonni
>   correction indicated primarily beneficial correlates of both of these variables. Exposure to
>   parental nudity was associated with positive, rather than negative, sexual experiences in
>   adolescence, but with reduced sexual experience overall. Boys exposed to parental nudity
>   were less likely to have engaged in theft in adolescence or to have used various
>   psychedelic drugs and marijuana.
>
> Taken as a whole then, effects are few, but generally beneficial in nature. Thus, results of
>   this study add weight to the views of those who have opposed alarmist characterizations
>   of childhood exposure both to nudity and incidental scenes of parental sexuality.

This is very likely the kind of thing (historically speaking, of course, which the paper touches on) that the MPAA and the government bases such things upon. Mostly this seems to harken back to Freud and early students thereof, who assumed that nearly every psychological disorder originated from witnessing such things as a small child. The paper linked above questions this assumption and tries to find actual clinical research to support the claim.

Comment: I think it is important to keep in mind, with regards to the parental nudity and sexual activity witnessing study, that it can not distinguish between harm caused by social effects and the events themselves. Prior to the Industrial Age, lower-class families slept, and had sex, in common rooms. Exposure to parental nudity and sexual activity was universal and normalized. Its effects would be radically different in our society, and harm would be more likely from social effects than the nudity or sex viewing itself.

Comment: If the "modesty of the Victorian era was in fact harmful" and this has been  "proven by many studies before and since," why not link to some of those studies?

Answer (score 24):

According to the [Rand Corporation](http://www.rand.org/pubs/research_briefs/RB9068/index1.html) and the [American Academy of Pediatrics](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/114/3/e280.full), watching sex on TV is correlated to earlier sexual activity.

From [1](http://www.rand.org/pubs/research_briefs/RB9068/index1.html):

> The results showed that heavy exposure
>   to sexual content on television
>   related strongly to teens’ initiation
>   of intercourse or their progression to
>   more advanced sexual activities (such
>   as “making out” or oral sex) apart
>   from intercourse in the following
>   year. Youths who viewed the greatest
>   amounts of sexual content were two
>   times more likely than those who
>   viewed the smallest amount to initiate
>   sexual intercourse during the
>   following year (see figure) or to
>   progress to more-advanced levels of
>   other sexual activity. In effect,
>   youths who watched the most sexual
>   content “acted older”: a 12-year-old
>   at the highest levels of exposure
>   behaved like a 14- or 15-year-old at
>   the lowest levels.

From [2](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/114/3/e280.full):

> Results. Multivariate regression
>   analysis indicated that adolescents
>   who viewed more sexual content at
>   baseline were more likely to initiate
>   intercourse and progress to more
>   advanced noncoital sexual activities
>   during the subsequent year,
>   controlling for respondent
>   characteristics that might otherwise
>   explain these relationships. The size
>   of the adjusted intercourse effect was
>   such that youths in the 90th
>   percentile of TV sex viewing had a
>   predicted probability of intercourse
>   initiation that was approximately
>   double that of youths in the 10th
>   percentile, for all ages studied.
>   Exposure to TV that included only talk
>   about sex was associated with the same
>   risks as exposure to TV that depicted
>   sexual behavior. African American
>   youths who watched more depictions of
>   sexual risks or safety were less
>   likely to initiate intercourse in the
>   subsequent year.

Comment: Hi, if you could (for the purpose of completeness) cite the relevant conclusions in brief here in your answer, I'd be very happy. Also, I would not automatically consider earlier sexual activity as harmful. Only if contraception is ignored, or if children develop psychological issues towards sex.

Comment: Thank you dan for your answer, but (earlier) sexual activities are by no means harmful on their own. It's still interesting researches nevertheless.

Comment: There are a couple of things worth noting here: the second link is way better than the first as it gives us a peer-reviewed study. The study makes some interesting points: 1. That there is a lot of simple correlation between age of sex and tv watching: teens that are interested in sex, watch a lot of sex-related tv and have sex. 2. They do correct for this against other predictors they researched, however they do not state they are sure there aren't other predictors. 3. They explicitly admit the possibility of prior interest as an explanation. Personally, I am surprised they forgot (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) an obvious predictor such as the age of puberty. I for one would like to see how much correlation this factor takes away from the results.

Comment: By the way, the second study contradicts the first on how much the teens "acted older", they found 9 to 17 months. Now - this is also surprising: how do you distinguish a 14 years old from a 14 years and 9 months old? I don't think such numbers make much sense...

Comment: @Sejanus *"(earlier) sexual activities are by no means harmful on their own."* **Citation required.** You did clearly state in comments to your question that you left the definition of "harmful" up to the answerer. If you've decided to change your question, and choose to define harmful yourself, you should clearly state such in the question. Honestly I wish people wouldn't post such poor questions on skeptics, but I suppose it's par for the course.

Comment: no Adam, it would be up to the source claiming it is harmful to state why. This source makes a (questionable) conclusion without afaik making claims the observed behaviour is harmful (and rightly so, a scientific study should make no moral or cultural claims, and anything to do with sexuality like this is by its very nature moral or cultural).

Answer (score -2):

> The fact is that most children explore pornography at some time in
>   their lives, and there is no statistical evidence that it causes
>   specific harm. Of course, what matters is how a child engages with
>   this material. A passing curiosity may be easily satisfied and the
>   interest abandoned; but sexual images have a special vividness and
>   power, and may become addictive, as can many other internet
>   activities, such as chatting or shopping or gaming. Personal accounts
>   by people who have developed an obsession with pornography are
>   disturbing: "It almost lodges itself into your mind, like a parasite
>   sucking away the rest of your life," explains 16-year-old Malcolm, who
>   participated in a 2007 study and reported spending between three to
>   four hours each day visiting pornographic sites.
>   http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/features/teenage-kicks-is-internet-porn-creating-a-damaged-generation-1938238.html